# Finding xpath or cssSelector locations for all

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop, exception

I am relatively new to development so please forgive me if some of this seems rather amateurish. Part of my reason for posting the question is to help nudge me to the answer, part is to make sure I'm following good coding practice.

The challenge -

I'm using Java & Selenium to check a very large, dynamically populated table. I need to find a specific list of elements where the text matches a case-sensitive String -

```
List<WebElement> AllPaths = getCurrentDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + fixedString + "')]]"));
```

The table I'm checking is basically a large calendar-style grid. If I don't find evidence of fixedString, I then want to iterate back one month at a time until I DO find the fixedString.

The problem -

The code above returns an exception if it cannot find an element. My first thought was to setup a while loop, trying/catching the exception and then repeating until exceptions stopped. However this feels wrong to me - I don't think I should be essentially "swallowing" exceptions.  That said, I'm not sure what the correct way of trying to find this element is that doesn't lead to an exception if it fails to locate it.

Am I right in thinking it's a bad idea to write code that you know causes an exception and then simply swallow it and move on?

Hope this makes sense, as I say I'm a beginner so please be gentle :)

Comment: you should add the exception details to the question. I am assuming the fixedString does not have any quotes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like -

```
if(AllPaths.size()>0){
  //logic when elements found with fixed string
}else{
//logic to iterate over another month
}
```

Also, your statement seems wrong to me. It should be -

```
List<WebElement> AllPaths = getCurrentDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + fixedString + "')]"));
```

`findElements` doesn't throw exception this way. It will return empty if no elements located. The exception seems due to incorrect statement that you are using to find elements.

Comment: according to @david_c the line of code in the question throws exception, not the subsequent handling of the result. So this if check will not help.

Comment: Thanks gagan singh. I did update the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, this seems like the cause of the failure. david can confirm what exception he was getting.

Comment: This worked. The exception was NoSuchElement and although I've refactored the code to look more like the above now, and can't see my original, I agree it's likely I was using FindElement rather than FindElements.

Answer (score 1):

> The code above returns an exception if it cannot find an element.

The documentation says [`findElements`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns an empty list when no elements are found. It should not throw any exception in this case. Is it possible that you by mistake used `findElement` instead of `findElements`? What type of exception is thrown and what is the message?

You shouldn't need to catch exceptions here. You are right though that control flow using exceptions should be avoided and that swallowing exceptions is bad. On the other hand frameworks don't always let you write code the way you want so sometimes exceptions have to be made.